# Forcing an "Offline" Mode in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are building an app for our teams out in the field that they collect their daily information using Firebase. However one of our concerns is poor connectivity. We are looking to build an Online/Offline button they can click to essentially work offline for when things slow down. We've built a workflow in which we query all the relevant information from Firestore.

I wanted to know if there was a way to tell Firestore to work directly on the cache only and not try to hit the servers directly. I don't want Firestore attempting to make server calls until they enable online again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this. If you use realtime listeners, they will already first return the data from the local cache, and only then reach out to the server to check for updates.

If you are performing one-time reads, the SDK will by default try to reach the server first (since it has only one chance to give you a value). If you want it to only check the local cache, you can [pass an argument to the get call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GetOptions) to do so.

You can also disable the network completely, in which case the client will never call on the network and only serve from the local cache. I recommend reading about that and more in the documentation on [using Firestore offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).